# CSS Emotion Library - Getting css props error when using css prop

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

This is my code

```
import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/core'
       
return (
       <>
       <img css={css`height: 200px; height: 200px;`} fluid={image.sharp.fluid} />
       <List>
           <li>Our Clients</li>
           <li>What We Do</li>
           <li>Contact</li>
       </List>
       </>
   )
```

This is the error I'm getting

> You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It
> isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className`
> prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value
> of `css` prop).

This error seems to be telling me that I need to do what I am already doing? Or am I missing something here.

Comment: can you share your `.babelrc` ?

Answer (score 29):

Just wanted to note I had this issue and adding this fixed the error for me:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/core';
```

Just to clarify, you have to add `/** @jsx jsx */;` at the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks. I think this should highlight in the emotion documentation too

Comment: This is highlighted in the emotion docs now under the Typescript section. Note that it precludes you from using <></> shorthand. You can still use Fragment
https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript

Comment: @shallow.alchemy What if we're not using typescript ?

Comment: Thanks this saved me a lot of messing around i thought that was a comment! I found this updated version:
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */

Answer (score 26):

This method solved my problem:

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import { css } from "@emotion/react"

export default function somepage() {

  const color = 'red'

  return (<div
    css={css`
      background-color: hotpink;
      &:hover {
        color: ${color};
      }
    `}
  >
    Hello World.
  </div>)
}
```

What Does this do?

If you are using a zero-config tool with automatic detection of which runtime (classic vs. automatic) should be used and you are already using a React version that has the new JSX runtimes (hence **runtime: 'automatic'** being configured automatically for you) such as Create React App 4 then `/** @jsx jsx */` pragma might not work and you should use `/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */` instead.

Comment: What does it do ?

Comment: @Monstar read this: [https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma)

Comment: This worked for me!  From that link above: `If you are using a zero-config tool with automatic detection of which runtime (classic vs. automatic) should be used and you are already using a React version that has the new JSX runtimes (hence runtime: 'automatic' being configured automatically for you) such as Create React App 4 then /** @jsx jsx */ pragma might not work and you should use /** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */ instead.`

Answer (score 17):

As [detailed in the Emotion documentation](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop), use of the `css` prop requires you to replace `React` with `jsx` as the target function for JSX elements (known as the “pragma”), which will enable Emotion to intercept the `css` prop and transform it into a `className` prop for React.

For example:

```
<p>Hi</p>

// Becomes the following by default:
React.createElement("p", {}, "Hi")

// But with the `jsx` pragma, it becomes:
jsx("p", {}, "Hi")
```

There are two outlined approaches to achieve this. You only need to select one. If you are able to configure Babel in your application, the first is the recommended approach, but either one works fine:

1. [Install a Babel plugin](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#babel-preset) that will configure `jsx` as the default handler for all code in your app

   The most direct way to do this is by adding the relevant Babel preset to your Babel configuration like so:

   ```
   // Option 1A — Good
   // Add @emotion/babel-preset-css-prop to your dev dependencies, then
   // add the preset to your .babelrc configuration:

   {
     "presets": ["@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop"]
   }
   ```

   If you are able to do this, though, I recommend instead configuring [babel-plugin-emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/babel-plugin), which includes the `css` prop configuration as well other features like minification, dead code elimination, and hoisting:

   ```
   // Option 1B — Better
   // Add babel-plugin-emotion to your dev dependencies, then add
   // the plugin to your Babel configuration (e.g. .babelrc)
   {
     "plugins": ["emotion"]
   }
   ```
2. Import the `jsx` function from Emotion and instruct Babel to use this imported function [on a per-file basis using pragma](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma)

   ```js
   /** @jsx jsx */
   import { jsx } from '@emotion/core'
   ```

Comment: In my case after following your suggestion I was encountering **[this]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965774/emotion-css-prop-and-nextjs-new-jsx-runtime-error-pragma-and-pragmafrag-canno) problem and replacing step 2 with`/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */` fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install this babel plugin, [babel-preset-css-prop](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-css-prop)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to include the `@emotion/babel-plugin`, there was some configuration that I have missed that created that error.

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      { "runtime": "automatic", "importSource": "@emotion/react" }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@emotion/babel-plugin"]
}
```

The `"importSource": "@emotion/react"` was missing. After adding it, the error was gone and the styles were implemented correc5y.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to get started with the css prop.

1. [Babel Preset](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#babel-preset)
2. [JSX Pragma](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma)

Both methods result in the same compiled code.

---

## JSX Pragma

Set the jsx pragma at the top of your source file that uses the css prop. This option works best for testing out the css prop feature or in projects where the babel configuration is not configurable (create-react-app, codesandbox, etc.).

```
/** @jsx jsx */
```

if it didn't work use:

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
```

---

## Babel Preset

This method will **not work** with **Create React App** or other projects that do not allow custom Babel configurations. Use the JSX Pragma method instead.

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop"]
}
```

---

Couldn't solve your problem? Consider reading official documentation:
**https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop**

Answer (score -6):

/**@jsx jsx */
import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/core'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it answers the question, so that it is also useful for other users with similar a problem, as well as the OP. Also, please format your code correctly.