# Emotion CSS Prop and Nextjs new JSX runtime - error: pragma and pragmaFrag cannot be set when runtime is automatic

Tags: next.js, emotion

I'm trying to use the CSS Prop of Emotion 11 with Nextjs 10.1
Following the documentation, my .babelrc file is the following:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel",
      {
        "preset-react": {
          "runtime": "automatic",
          "importSource": "@emotion/react"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@emotion/babel-plugin"]
}
```

An my Nextjs page:

```js
/** @jsx jsx */
import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/react'

export default function testPage() {
  const color = 'darkgreen'
  return (<div
    css={css`
      background-color: hotpink;
      &:hover {
        color: ${color};
      }
    `}
  >
    This has a hotpink background.
  </div>)
}
```

I get the following error :

> pragma and pragmaFrag cannot be set when runtime is automatic.

If I remove the pragma `/** @jsx jsx */` I get this in the HTML code:

```
<div css="You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop).">This has a hotpink background.</div>
```

These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.2.0",
    "next": "^10.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The easiest way to solve it was to replace the `/** @jsx jsx */` by `/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */` and I don't even need to import jsx anymore:

```js
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import { css } from "@emotion/react"

export default function testPage() {
  const color = 'darkgreen'
  return (<div
    css={css`
      background-color: hotpink;
      &:hover {
        color: ${color};
      }
    `}
  >
    This has a hotpink background.
  </div>)
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me with latest versions of React and Emotion. (using CRA)

Comment: Awesome, works first time. Enabled me to remove all sorts of horrific custom config 

Answer (score 9):

In my case I added classic jsxrun time

```
/** @jsxRuntime classic */
/** @jsx jsx */
import { css } from "@emotion/react"
```

Answer (score 2):

I realized that I was running with nodejs 12. Just changed node version to 14 using nvm and it worked.