# How do I fix this css prop horror show using emotion/twin.macro?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, pragma, emotion, react-app-rewired

I am struggling to get my [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro) setup working in my React app. I cannot provide an entire history of what I've tried, since I have tried dozens of different things, but I will outline my current setup and outline what is not working.

I am using `react-app-rewired` because it seems I need a custom Babel configuration which apparently `create-react-app` does not support. For completeness, here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.16.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.5",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.8",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.45",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "d3": "^7.6.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.4",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "^4.1.0",
    "radash": "^7.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.0",
    "react-window": "^1.8.7",
    "recharts": "^2.1.14",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "twin.macro": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
    "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop": "^11.10.0",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/react-csv": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/react-window": "^1.8.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-twin": "^1.1.0",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My `.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-twin",
    "babel-plugin-macros"
  ],
  "presets": ["@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop"]
}
```

My `babel-plugin-macros.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  twin: {
    preset: "emotion"
  }
}
```

My `config-overrides.js` looks like this:

```
const { useBabelRc, override } = require("customize-cra");
module.exports = override(useBabelRc());
```

Thinks that's the entire pertinent config.

So I have this component:

```
/** @jsxRuntime classic /
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'

const StatsHeader = ({ status, title }: Props) => (
  <div tw="bg-red-100">
    <span tw="text-red-500">Hello</span>
  </div>
);
```

...which currently yields the following markup:

```
<span css="You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop)." data-tw="text-red-500">Hello</span>
```

Removing the `/** @jsxRuntime classic /` from the top of the file gives rise to a complaint about runtime being automatic, which makes me think the `react-app-rewired` is not really working? Perhaps? Since it is supposed to create a custom environment?

In any case, the reason I installed the `react-app-rewired` was in response to the `css` prop giving an `[Object object]` in the markup, so if I could fix that and revert, that would probably be a better solution.

Suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why you need `react-app-rewired`. I think it should not be needed for a standard `Twin.macro` setup. I've followed this [blog post](https://medium.com/swlh/twin-macro-on-cra-with-react-17-e95c54f88097) and it is working - just changed the Tailwind css import in index.js. So only adding the "babelMacros" key in `package.json` pointing to your `tailwind.config.js` should be enough to get everything setup.

Answer (score 1):

Not to worry. I got rid of all the smelly custom config because I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968415/343159) that suggested this:

`/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */`

...at the top of the file, which works with `create-react-app`. Solved!